# Clojure list inside list declaration

Tags: list, syntax, clojure

I was trying to declare a list inside list in Clojure.

```
Expected behavior: `(`()) => (())
Actual behavior:   `(`()) => ((clojure.core/list))
```

What does that output mean?

Also, I would like to understand how the behavior below is consistent.

```
`()     => ()
`("hi") => ("hi")
`(`())  => ((clojure.core/list))
```

Unrelated to my question, here's a code snippet which actually returns `(())`:

```
(conj `() `())
```

Answer (score 2):

Basically, don't nest quotes. I'm going to use the basic [`quote`](https://clojuredocs.org/search?q=quote) special form here, but the same concepts apply to the more complex syntax quote as well.

When you write this:

```
'()
;;=> ()
```

That's *exactly the same* as writing this:

```
(quote ())
;;=> ()
```

So when you write this:

```
'('())
;;=> ((quote ()))
```

That's the same as writing this:

```
(quote ((quote ())))
;;=> ((quote ()))
```

One thing you can do is just quote the outermost list:

```
'(())
;;=> (())
```

Or you can the [`list`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/list) function, which is a far more general solution:

```
(list)
;;=> ()

(list "hi")
;;=> ("hi")

(list (list))
;;=> (())

(list 1 (+ 1 1) 3)
;;=> (1 2 3)
```