# count-leaves in Clojure from SICP

Tags: clojure, lisp, sicp

I'm going over SICP translating problems into Clojure to learn both Clojure and read SICP. Currently, I am stuck with the Count Leaves procedure from Section 2.2.2.

The goal is to write a function that takes a list representation of a tree, e.g. '(1 2 '(3 4)) and counts the number of leaves, in this case 4.

So far, the closest I have come up with is

```
(defn count-leaves
  [coll]
  (cond
    (nil? coll) 0
    (not (seq? coll)) 1
    :else (let [[left & right] coll] (+ (count-leaves left) (count-leaves right)))
    ))
```

However, this does not handle subtrees correctly. In particular, it evaluates

```
(count-leaves '('(1)))
```

to 2 instead of 1.

Note the Scheme implementation [from the book](https://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/full-text/book/book-Z-H-15.html#%25_sec_2.2.2) is:

```
(define (count-leaves x)
  (cond ((null? x) 0)
        ((not (pair? x)) 1)
        (else (+ (count-leaves (car x))
                 (count-leaves (cdr x))))))
```

Comment: "...evaluates `(count-leaves '('(1)))` to 2..." - As it should. `'('(1))` evaluates to `((quote (1)))`. Don't quote sublists inside already quoted lists.

Comment: Thank you, I thought '('(1)) was the same as (list (list 1)), but clearly I was wrong. For more: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38515614/clojure-list-inside-list-declaration

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Comment**

As @jkiski's comment suggests, your code works. So there is no problem.

But I'd prefer to test  whether the argument is a sequence first. Try working out how `(count-leaves '())` evaluates to `0`!

Switch the first two clauses of the `cond` and we get ...

```
(defn count-leaves [coll]
  (cond
    (not (seq? coll)) 1
    (empty? coll) 0
    :else (+ (count-leaves (first coll)) (count-leaves (rest coll)))))
```

... where I've used `rest` instead of the `next` implicit in the destructuring, so `empty?` instead of `nil?` to test it. This deals properly with `nil` values, which your code doesn't. But it is still properly recursive, so remains subject to stack overflow.

I prefer ...

```
(defn count-leaves [coll]
  (if (seq? coll)
    (apply + (map count-leaves coll))
    1))
```

... which is still recursive, but cleaner.

---

**Edit**

I've had to retract my good opinion of [@glts's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41521019/1562315): `postwalk` is recursive, so offers no real advantage.

Answer (score 2):

Translating examples from one language into another is a good exercise, but do keep in mind that a language also comes with its own idiom, and its own core library.

In Clojure, walking data structures is especially easy with [clojure.walk](https://clojure.github.io/clojure/clojure.walk-api.html).

After requiring `clojure.walk` you can run `postwalk-demo` to see how your data structure is traversed:

```clj
(require '[clojure.walk :refer [postwalk postwalk-demo]])
(postwalk-demo '(1 2 (3 4)))
```

```
Walked: 1
Walked: 2
Walked: 3
Walked: 4
Walked: (3 4)
Walked: (1 2 (3 4))
```

Then you can devise a function to count the leaf nodes and pass it to `postwalk`.

```clj
(postwalk (fn [e]
            (if (seq? e) (apply + e) 1))
          '(1 2 (3 4)))
```

During the postwalk traversal leaf nodes get replaced with 1, and seqs get replaced with the sum of their constituent leaf counts.

I realise that this is a tangential answer but perhaps you still find it useful!